# Request on k8s NGINX ingress controller fails with "upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream"

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

When I try to send a request through my NGINX ingress with headers larger than 4k, it returns a 502 error:

```
[error] 39#39: *356 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, 
    client: <ip>,
    server: <server>, 
    request: "GET /path/ HTTP/1.1", 
    subrequest: "/_external-auth-Lw", 
    upstream: "<uri>", 
    host: "<host>"
[error] 39#39: *356 auth request unexpected status: 502 while sending to client, 
    client: <ip>, 
    server: <server>, 
    request: "GET /path/ HTTP/1.1", 
    host: "<host>"
```

I've followed instructions about how to allegedly resolve this issue by configuring the `proxy-buffer-size` in the ingress controller (`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "16k"`), but it doesn't seem to work. The only thing that I can think of, is that it has something to do with the `proxy-buffer-size` of the subrequest, which doesn't seem to get set.

Answer (score 1):

The proxy_buffering header wasn't being set on the /_external-auth-Lw endpoint in the NGINX config. Issue has been resolved as of v. 0.14.0.